# Python: Convert Column of letters into number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read in a csv file into a pandas dataframe and have something like this:

```
  A B C D ...Z
1 5 P 8 H ...1
2 5 K 8 K ...2
3 6 K 8 K ...5
```

How do I convert Column B and Column D (and any other columns in dataframe) into a number? It could be A =1, B =2, etc OR I tried ord() function but it would not accept the entire Series.

Comment: `ord(field) - ord('A') + 1`

Comment: ord(test.['Column b']) - ord('A') + 1 but got similar Series error

Comment: Read the line into a string, split it at spaces into a list. Then use that `ord()` function on `list[2]` and `list[4]`.

Comment: I'm still learning python, how would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry are you wanting `df.applymap(ord)`?

Comment: `df.B.astype('category').cat.codes`

Answer (score 6):

1. You can use this for column A for example:

   `dataframe.A = [ ord(x) for x in dataframe.A ]`
2. If you want A to be 1, B to be 2 etc...

   `dataframe.A = [ ord(x) - 64 for x in dataframe.A ]`

Comment: The #2 is perfect! Thanks YOBA!

Comment: Sure @user2977664 , anytime, I guess you can mark the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
for line in lines:
   new_line = map(lambda x: ord(x) - 64 if x.isalpha() else x, line)
```

Go through the matrix line by line, than apply in each element `ord()- 65` if it is an alphabet else use it as it is. `64` is `ord("A")-1`.