# Convert letter into numeric value

Tags: python, pandas, letter

I have column in Pandas dataframe which has values from A-Z. I want to replace the letter value into numeric value.
i.e A = 1, B = 2 etc

I tried below and it works but is there an efficient way to replace the value to numeric?

```
key = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8, 'I': 9,
       'J': 10, 'K': 11, 'L': 12, 'M': 13, 'N': 14, 'O': 15, 'P': 16, 'Q': 17,
       'R': 18, 'S': 19, 'T': 20, 'U': 21, 'V': 22, 'W': 23, 'X': 24, 'Y': 25,
       'Z': 26}

df.replace({'letter_column': key})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Convert Column of letters into number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106431/python-convert-column-of-letters-into-number)

Comment: Check if you have leading or trailing whitespace in your column. Use `df['letter_column'].str.strip().replace(key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
df = df.replace({'letter_column': {chr(i + 64): i for i in range(1, 27)}})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ord() which maps ASCII characters:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','B','C'], columns = ['letter'])

df['letter'].apply(lambda x:ord(x)-64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df[:] = df.to_numpy().astype('<U1').view(np.uint32)-64
```

Comment: Sweet! `view` - really cool little function.

Comment: `.values` is deprecated in favor of `.to_numpy()`, by the way. I updated your code (revert it if you want :)